# Okular print multiple pages per sheet has been greyed-out/deactivated

Tags: pdf, printing, kde, okular

As the question goes, the page setup options remain greyed out whenever I want to print multiple pages a side and save it as a pdf document in a file (the print to file option). I do not have a working printer so I cannot say whether the problem persists there too. I am using a fresh install of Manjaro 20.2. Am I missing something out/doing something wrong?

[image: Photo for reference]